# iOS Make a welcome page before main StoryBoard in swift

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, storyboard, uitabbarcontroller

I am working on create a welcome page when App running in the first time.
Actually, I already finished everything of this App UI, but everything based on storyboard. (so, 'fun application' was empty in AppDelegate.swift)

Now, I have designed a welcome page based on code "welcomeController()"

And I added following code in AppDelegate -> fun application to check whether lunching

```
    window = UIWindow(frame: ScreenBounds)
    window!.makeKeyAndVisible()

    let isFristOpen = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("isFristOpenApp")

    if isFristOpen == nil {
        window?.rootViewController =  welcomeController()
        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject("isFristOpenApp", forKey: "isFristOpenApp")
    }else {
        window!.rootViewController = MainTabBarController()
    }
```

welcome page works fine, but MainTabBarController() (was identified in the storyboard)just shown blank. And when I click finished button(call "window!.rootViewController = MainTabBarController()" by Notification centre) in the last page of welcome page, it shown blank as well (of course).

So, how could I achieved such requirement? Maybe the same thinking in Login?

Answer (score 2):

Try to instantiate your welcome screen not from AppDelegate, but from your initial ViewController.

In your initial ViewController in viewDidLoad() add checking for isFristOpenApp using NSUserDefaults, and if it's first time app exposured to user, you just call instantiate from storyboard using storyboard identifier. Like this:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {

let userDefaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()

let isFristOpen = userDefaults.boolForKey("isFristOpenApp")

        if isFristOpen == true {
            if let welcomeController = storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("WelcomeController") as? WelcomeController {

                self.presentViewController(welcomeController , animated: true, completion: nil)
            }

        }
}
```

And somewhere inside your welcomeController you can set isFirstOpen to false:

```
let userDefaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
userDefaults.setBool(false, forKey: "isFristOpenApp")
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do it this way:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {

    // show Welcome View

    let mainStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let welcomeController = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("welcomeController") as! WelcomeController
    self.window?.rootViewController = welcomeController

    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    return true
}
```

This will show the "welcome View" when the app will be started

And use this in the WelcomeView to load the MainTabBar

```
func showMainTab() {
    let mainStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let tabBarController = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("tabBarController") as! MainTabBarController
    let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
    appDelegate.window?.rootViewController = tabBarController
}
```